# Hash function that maps similar inputs to similar outputs?

Tags: algorithm, hash, hashcode, simhash

Is there a hash function where small changes in the input result in small changes in the output? For example, something like:

```
hash("Foo") => 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
hash("Foo!") => 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d7 <- note small difference
```

Comment: That would be a *really* bad hash algorithm....

Comment: For a cryptographic hash, yes, this would be bad, but I want to use it for something else.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details as to what is the intended purpose of such a function. 
There is definitely no cryptographic hash function with that property, but maybe you are looking for something different?

Comment: What is your definition of a "small change" in the output? Edit distance (treating hashes as strings) or mathematical distance of numbers (treating hashes as integers?)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call this a hash because the point of a hash is exactly the opposite.  However, with your stated goal of small changes in input producing small changes in output, I would look at using either a [soundex](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=soundex&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10) function or the [Ratcliff](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=ratcliff+obershelp&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g1) algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [simhash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/simhash.1.html), [algorithm](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/PageTurner/similarity.htm) by Mark Manasse.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution would be be to XOR all bytes module N. E.g. for a 64 bits hash, you'd XOR (input[0] ^ input[8] ^ input[16]) + 256*(input[1] ^ input[9] ^ input[17]) etc.
So, "Foo" hashes to "Foo\0\0\0\0\0" and "Foo!" hashes to "Foo!\0\0\0\0".

Answer (score 0):

> Locality-sensitive hashing (LSH) reduces the dimensionality of
>   high-dimensional data. LSH hashes input items so that similar items
>   map to the same “buckets” with high probability:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing

Here is a nice example of perceptual hashing on DNA sequences:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5517.pdf